# When to use non-additive stochastic error term

Tags: residuals, error

I have encountered the following two versions of the Cobb-Douglas production function as an illustration of the differences between *intrinsically* non-linear and *linearisable non-linear* regression models (and their transformations):

\begin{align}
Y_i & = \beta_1 X_{2i}^{\beta_2} X_{3i}^{\beta_3} u_i \\
Y_i & = \beta_1 X_{2i}^{\beta_2} X_{3i}^{\beta_3} + u_i
\end{align}

Where the first one can be transformed into a linear model, because the stochastic error term becomes additive:

\begin{align}
\ln Y_i & = \alpha + \beta_2 \ln X_{2i} + \beta_3 \ln X_{3i} + \ln u_i
\end{align}

The second model, however, cannot be transformed into a linear model because $\ln(A+B) \neq \ln A + \ln B$.

When is a non-additive error term ever used and why?

Comment: (+1) This subject is larger than you may think. As a *tiny* example of the subject-matter and data-analysis considerations that might enter into the choice of one model over the other, I offer [the first half of this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86360). Note that as much attention is paid to assessing the nature of the error terms as to evaluating the functional form of the relationship.